# How to choose which maven executions are run?

Tags: java, maven, xsd, wsdl, maven-dependency-plugin

### THE SETUP

I have a complex project that I'm trying to build using Maven.  What follows is a simplified example of that project.  The directory structure is as follows:

- main - The project has more than one 'ear', each of which contains more than one 'war' plus other supporting jars.  Yet they share a common set of WSDL/XSD, as well as Java code.

  - pom.xml - This is the main pom.xml file, I'll describe it in more detail below.
  - common-code-one - the two 'ear' package have a body of code in common, it's just java code, no wsdl, no xsd, so no problem.
  - wsdl - single package holding all the XSD and WSDL files, it has a pom.xml that simply packs it all up inside a jar file, for later use in sub-directories.
  - ear-package-one

    - common-code-two - Some of the XSD from 'wsdl' is unpacked here, and turned into code via jaxb2.  As part of that, an episode file is generated.
    - war-package-one - More of the XSD and WSDL files are unpacked here, and turned into code via jaxws.  To avoid having duplicate code, I need the episode file from 'common-code-two', **and** I need the XSD/WSDL files from 'wsdl'.
    - war-package-two - Different XSD/WSDL, but I still need the episode file from common-code-two, as well as the XSD/WSDL from 'wsdl'.
    - ejb-package-one - Don't need anything from 'wsdl', but may need some of the code from 'common-code-two', without needing the episode file.
    - ...
  - ear-package-two

    - common-code-two - Same problem, different XSD.
    - ejb-package-two - Same problem, different code.
    - war-package-three - Same problem, different XSD/WSDL.
    - war-package-four - Same problem, different XSD/WSDL.

Now, the main 'pom.xml' file.  Following Maven's DRY principle, I've put both executions of the maven-dependency-plugin into the main pom.xml.  The problem is that in some of the sub-packages above, I only want the 'unpack-schema' execution to run, in others I want **both** the 'unpack-schema' and 'unpack-common-binding' to run.  Of course, for the ones that don't need either, I just don't add the dependency plugin to the build list.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>

    <execution>
      <id>unpack-schema</id>
      <phase>generate-sources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>unpack</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
    <artifactItems>
      <artifactItem>
        <groupId>com.foo.bar</groupId>
        <artifactId>wsdl</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <overWrite>true</overWrite>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
        <includes>${schema.include.list}</includes>
      </artifactItem>
    </artifactItems>
    <overWriteReleases>true</overWriteReleases>
    <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
      </configuration>
    </execution>

    <execution>
      <id>unpack-common-binding</id>
      <phase>generate-sources</phase>
      <goals>
    <goal>unpack</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
    <artifactItems>
      <artifactItem>
        <groupId>com.foo.bar</groupId>
        <artifactId>${common.code.jar}</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <overWrite>true</overWrite>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
        <includes>**/commonCode.xml</includes>
      </artifactItem>
    </artifactItems>
    <overWriteReleases>true</overWriteReleases>
    <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
      </configuration>
    </execution>

  </executions>
</plugin>
```

### THE QUESTION

What do I put in the sub-projects' pom.xml files so that only the executions that are desired happen?

If I simply put in

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
...
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
...
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

then both executions happen.  In the 'war' packages, that's ok, that's what I want to have happen, but in the 'common-code' packages, I only want the 'unpack-schema' execution to happen.

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19301006/1608079) but it was never really answered, and the commented solution (run multiple builds) just isn't suitable for my environment.  This is going to be going through continuous integration/build, so it has to compile straight up.  No scripts, no multiple build passes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy, most plugins have an `<skip/>` configuration item, dependency plugin is no exception!

so, you can overwrite the pom of common-code with `<skip/>`to disable a certain execution! for example:

```
 <execution>
  <id>unpack-schema</id>
  <phase>generate-sources</phase>
  <goals>
    <goal>unpack</goal>
  </goals>
  <configuration>
    <skip>true</skip>
  </configuration>
</execution>
```

BTW: a tip for you: for multi-module projects, a plugin configured at parent pom.xml will run on all sub-modules, unless you disable it on sub-module's pom.xml with !

Good Luck!

Comment: Perfect!  Just what I needed!  I put the 'skip' setting in the parent pom, along with a default property 'skip.unpack.binding' setting of 'false', so that it won't be skipped in most cases.  Then I override 'skip.unpack.binding' to 'true' in those places where I don't want the unpack-common-binding execution to run.